# Build mongodb docker image for arm64 raspberry pi 4 using official or bitnami mongodb docker image

Tags: mongodb, docker, arm, kubernetes-helm, raspberry-pi4

I tried to install helm chart from bitnami/mongodb on arm64 raspberry pi 4 running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS 64bit. The container starts but then immediately terminates itself. I think it's because the mongodb image from bitnami isn't compatible with arm64 architecture.

How can I build mongodb or any other arm64 architecture compatible docker image or helm chart using the corresponding official docker image from x86_x64 laptop?

Comment: Any reason why you are not using mongo official image? https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo which seems to support ARM 64

Comment: I want to use helm chart to deploy on k8s. The helm chart from stable/mongodb is depreciated and bitnami/mongodb helm charts are maintained. Is it possible to modify bitnami/mongodb charts to become compatible with arm64?

Comment: I'd suggest to use the official Mongo ARM64 image (as mentioned by @β.εηοιτ.βε). You can start the Helm Chart with the following parameter: `--set image.repository=<arm64-based-docker-image>`.

Answer (score 2):

I made it work by modifying helm chart to pull arm64 compatible [image](https://hub.docker.com/r/arm64v8/mongo) of mongodb. Here is the code:

```
helm install mongodb bitnami/mongodb
  --set image.repository=arm64v8/mongo
  --set image.tag=latest
  --set persistence.mountPath=/data/db
```

These are the minimum set of config we need to override inorder to make it work. The rest of the environment parameters like `--set mongodbRootPassword=<?> --set mongodbUsername=<?> --set mongodbPassword=<?> --set mongodbDatabase=<?>` will **not** work on `arm64v8/mongo` image as these env params are `bitnami/mongodb` image specific. I suggest to modify `bitnami/mongodb` helm templete's to make it compatible with `arm64v8/mongo` environment variables